# Debugging Javascript in Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)

Tags: javascript, debugging, iife

Many Javascript applications encapsulate all of their modules/functions in IIFE's. This means the modules and functions aren't accesible in the browser console. Usually debugging works by littering the code with `console.log` statements. Is there a better way to write/debug Javascript?

Comment: Can't you set a breakpoint on source code in you browser (eg. Chrome)?

Comment: Have you tried using the JavaScript debugger that's present on most (all?) modern browsers? You can set breakpoints, inspect values, etc.

Comment: _"This means the modules and functions aren't accesible in the browser console"_ You can provide a name for the IIFE.

Comment: @IrvinDominin yes, I have tried setting breakpoints. Sometimes it's hard to find the code in the call stack though. What I'd like to do is use the console like a REPL and play with the currently running code.

Comment: You don't need the call stack. You can go into the Sources tab (in Chrome), go to the file containing the IIFE, and set the breakpoint in there.